# Android Design Support Library Secondary Drawer Menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I've switched to the official Google Design Support Library. Now, I want to use a secondary menu with a divider like this:

[image: Secondary Menu Screenshot]

But as Android is using the Menu Inflater I have no idea what to do now. I can add a second group, but then the items have the same size and there is no divider.

**drawer.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/overview"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_dashboard"
            android:title="@string/drawer_overview" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/social_evening"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_brightness_3"
            android:title="@string/drawer_social_evening" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/scouting_games"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_landscape"
            android:title="@string/drawer_scouting_games" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/olympics"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_stars"
            android:title="@string/drawer_olympics" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/quizzes"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_school"
            android:title="@string/drawer_quizzes" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package net.sutomaji.freizeitspiele;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Tom Schneider on 18.06.15
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Defining Variables
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);Q

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.overview:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Overview Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.social_evening:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SE Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.scouting_games:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SG Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.olympics:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OL Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.quizzes:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"QZ Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();






    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So, how can I create a menu like this, or how can I add dividers (with category headers) to my navigation drawer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the standard `NavigationView` defining a menu like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="single" id>
       //items of group1
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/group2" android:checkableBehavior="single" id>
       //items of group2
    </group>
```

It is important to give an unique id to each group.

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial: [Navigation View Design Support Library](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-navigation-drawer-view.html)

Menu Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_attachment"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_attachment"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_attachment" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_images"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_image"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_images" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_location"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_place"
            android:title="@string/nav_item_location" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/nav_sub_menu">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_emoticon"
                android:title="@string/nav_sub_menu_item01" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_emoticon"
                android:title="@string/nav_sub_menu_item02" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what you exactly looking for:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Home"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/homestr" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/myacc"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
            android:title="@string/myaccstr" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/popular"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:title="@string/Popularstr" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/newsit"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_news"
            android:title="@string/newsstr" />


        <item android:title="@string/gn">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/settings"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:title="@string/action_settings" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/help"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
                    android:title="@string/helpstr" />

            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use any ViewGroup like a LinearLayout for your Drawer. It is not limited to a ListView and a FrameLayout. Because of this you can style your Drawer View like any other layout of an Activity for example. The only thing you should keep in mind is that the NavigationDrawer can have only two childs. The first is your layout for the Activity and the second is the Drawer. Feel free to style them as you like!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- YOUR DRAWER -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <!-- Use any Views you like -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

for the divider

```
android:divider="#FFFFFF"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
```

Comment: The question is targeted to using the NavigationView with inflating the menu from a resources file